# При запросе выдает ошибку mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: Failed executing the operation; Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql, база-данных

Нужно было переделать с `sqlite` на `mysql` запросы в `python`. Для `sqlite` всё работало. ? менял на `%s`, не помогло. Использую библиотеку `mysql-connector-python`

```
    def write_groups(self,groups):
        groups_list = [[i[0],i[1]] for i in groups]
        #try:

        self.cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO groups (name,image) VALUES (?,?)",groups_list)
        self.mysql_connection.commit()
        print("успешно")
        exit()
        #except:
            #pass
```

В случае этого запроса `parent_id` остается `null`, поэтому его не использую. Пробовал писать его в запрос как `None` значение - не помогло.
Код таблицы баз данных

```
CREATE TABLE `groups` (
  `id_group` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `image` BLOB,
  `parent_id` INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY USING BTREE (`id_group`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci'
;
```